# Openlayers: problem with scaleline and measurement

Tags: openlayers, distance

I have detected the following problem in my viewer based on openlayers.
My coordinate system is: 4326.
And I have a measurement tool based on a custom function as I am working with geographical coordinates.

I have detected that the results are good but as I am moving forward the north (up to 50º latitude), the results are wrong.

In addition, I have tried with a projectected system as 3857 and in this case I see that the scaleline is ok for the default viewport but If I change the scale or location the results are wrong. in this case, I make the measeurements with getLength from ol.sphere.

You can reproduce the problem if you make the following changes to the next openlayers example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

Click on edit and then apply the following changes
:

1. Import the following libraries:
   import ScaleLine from 'ol/control/ScaleLine';
   import { defaults as defaultControls } from 'ol/control';
2. Update the map variable by the next one:

```
  const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 15,
  }),
  controls: defaultControls({
    attributionOptions: ({
      collapsible: true,
      collapsed: false
    })
  }).extend([ new ScaleLine()])
});
```

Then, if you zoom out until the scaleline is 2000km, you will see the next results (see image attached):
scaliline:2000km
measurement 4051.21Km

Please, does anyone know how to fix it?

Best regards.
Clara

Comment: The scalebar shows the scale at the center of the view, but the scale can differ across the map depending on the projection, e.g. in https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZsmt.png a 2000km line at latitude 60 looks twice as long as one at the equator.

Comment: Dear Mike, many thanks for your response!. I have checked with epsg3857 and it is true that the scaleline length matches the distance in the center of the view. But if I change the system to 4326, in this case, it does not matches the center of the view. Do you know why? Many thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: In EPSG:4326 the scale on the y axis is the same at all latitudes but the x axis is latitude dependent (so away from the equator a 2000km horizontal line would look longer than a 2000km vertical line).  The scalebar shows the average of the two dimensions.